# Thread safety issue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a LinkedList with Objects, that I want to process. Objects get added to it from another thread, but only one Thread removes/reads from it.

```
private LinkedList<MyObject> queue = new LinkedList<>();

new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            if (!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                MyObject first = queue.removeFirst();
                // do sth..
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

In another Thread I add Objects to the queue

```
queue.add(new MyObject());
```

**Sometimes this code leads to an Exception though, which I cant really explain to myself.**
Exception in thread "" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)

I dont get, why I get this Exception, since it should only try to remove an object if one exists.

Comment: Your consumer thread does the "busy waiting" when the queue is empty. You should probably fix it as well.

Comment: A bit silly, but since these things can be very hard to predict I suggest you make extra sure that there really is only one thread calling that removeFirst method. Add a print of the thread id inside the if statement.

Comment: @TheFooBarWay It doesn't matter whether there is one consumer or two. There are multiple producers which is enough to cause synchronisation problems. If you have more than one thread modifying the object, it has to be synchronised. If you had exactly one thread modifying and multiple threads reading, then it could be unsynchronised (but iterating might be tricky).

Comment: I would say it depends on LinkedList's implementation. The "add" operation is not atomic, so `isEmpty` could return false before the element is actually reachable through `removeFirst`. But that's only speculation.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, that could explain the behaviour. I didnt come up with a possible cause, but this could be it.

Comment: @BluE this is exactly why it doesn't make any sense to try to provide a reason, you will only have random guesses no real answers, just use TS collections as proposed instead of wasting time to understand why something that you misuse doesn't work. Otherwise your question is purely a primary opinion based and will be closed

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Youre right about the busy waiting too. That shouldnt have been like that.

Comment: @Fildor I don't think this is the reason, `LinkedList.linkLast(E)` first adds the node, and then updates `size`.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I will use a thread safe list instead to fix my problem.
But I do think it does make sense to think about it. For me understanding why and how the problem occured is important, because I can remember things better that I understand. So I would less likely make the same mistake again.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I just saw this, too. But I do not share your conclusion. Fact is: the Exception *is* thrown. So there must be some kind of sync-issue. Maybe the updated `int`value ("size") is visible faster than the updated reference ("last")? Who knows? But I am at the point where I agree with "not worth further investigation". It's concurrency - sync or bust.

Comment: @Fildor exactlly, non-volatile fields used in multiple threads cause problems.

Comment: What I can tell you for sure is that it is not related to size as mentioned here previously, according to my tests it is related to the fact the list get broken such that in `unlinkFirst` at some point we face a situation where `first = next`  affects `null` to `first` while `size > 0` so the next call to `removeFirst()` throws `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you! I think I get how that could happen when using a not thread save list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nicolas has already mentioned, you need a thread safe implementation. I would recommend using `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

You can add to it using `offer` method and remove using `take` which will also resolve your "busy waiting" problem.

Comment: All true but it does answer the actual question which is how we end up with an exception. If there truly is just the one thread removing items then we can linear the code at the if statement and the run should be legal.

Comment: @TheFooBarWay I don't think it is worth the effort of going into implementation details and investigating what assignment happens where etc. It's unsynchronised, such problems might happen.

Comment: Not worth the effort maybe, if you come from programmers point of view. But these are often interesting academic questions. 

I'm nitpicking I suppose, but it feels like we miss the real question here when suggesting a thread safe solution. It's like showing a kid how to do long division by using a calculator. 

Other than that you're right.

Comment: I guess its both. Of course I want to fix my code with a thread-safe implementation, but I also want to know how the situation happened. Fildor commented on the question with the likely cause.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I have used the LinkedBlockingQueue before and will most likely use it for this usecase.
I would use the take() method instead of polling though.

Answer (score 0):

A `LinkedList` is **not thread-safe** so you can't share it with several threads as you currently do otherwise you will face unpredictable bugs like this one due to concurrent modifications that lead to an inconsistent state, use instead a **thread-safe deque** such as [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html).

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote you and dont know why someone would.
I upvoted to cancel it out. Actually I had a hard time choosing the selected answer between this and the answer of Jaroslaw Pawlak, because both were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Although I think there have been a few good solutions offered as to how to resolve the problem, none of the answers explained why @BluE sees the NoSuchElementException. So here is what I think could be happening.

Since LinkedList access is not synchronized it is possible that:

1. The producer thread adds an element to the queue
2. Two consumer threads concurrently check for if (!queue.isEmpty()) and see that it is not.
3. Both consumer threads go ahead and try to take an element from the queue invoking MyObject first = queue.removeFirst();
4. One of the threads succeeds and the other one fails with a NoSuchElementException since there are no more elements in the queue.

   **UPDATE:**

Provided you have only one producer and one consumer, I think the Java Memory Model specification could explain the behaviour you see.

Long story short, since the access to the LinkedList is not synchronized there are no data visibility guarantees offered by the JVM. Let's have a look at the implementations of isEmpty and removeFirst methods:

From LinkedList

```
transient int size = 0;
transient Node<E> first;

// ...

public int More ...size() {
    return size;
}

// ...

public E removeFirst() {
    final Node<E> f = first;
    if (f == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return unlinkFirst(f);
}
```

From AbstractCollection

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}
```

As you can see, the size and the elements are stored in different variables. So it is possible that the consumer thread sees the updates on the "size" variable and does not see the updates on the "first".

Comment: Thanks for your guess, but that can't be it, since I only have one consumer.

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is to use some kind of technique to coordinate the threads, like Mutex, Semaphore, Monitor, Mailbox etc.