# Error linkedlist peek() not null and size() =0

Tags: java, linked-list

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public LinkedList<String> mylinkedlist;

/*...*/

System.out.println("STRING: "+ mylinkedlist.peek() +" SIZE: "+ mylinkedlist.size());
```

output

> STRING: blablabla SIZE: 0

it is a debugging question : How can `peek()` return a value and size of the list be 0 ?

**EDIT FEB 25 - Bug appear again**

The error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)
    at java.util.LinkedList.pop(LinkedList.java:801)
    at GrblCommunicator.streamCommands(GrblCommunicator.java:164)
    at GrblCommunicator.responseMessage(GrblCommunicator.java:234)
    at ResponseMessageHandler.handleResponse(ResponseMessageHandler.java:33)
    at SerialConnectionJserial.serialEvent(SerialConnectionJserial.java:114)
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort$SerialPortEventListener.waitForSerialEvent(SerialPort.java:1387)
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort$SerialPortEventListener$1.run(SerialPort.java:1300)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

/*...*/

public volatile LinkedList<String> commandBuffer;     


public void streamCommands() {

        if (this.commandBuffer.size() == 0) {
            // NO-OP
            return;
        }

        if (this.sendPaused) {
            // Another NO-OP
            return;
        }


        while (CommUtils.checkRoomInBuffer(this.sentBufferSize, this.commandBuffer.peek())
                && allowMoreCommands()) {

            if(this.commandBuffer.size()==0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR DE COMMAND BUFFER SIZE GrblComm 155: ");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                 String commandString = this.commandBuffer.pop();
```

LINE 164 is : this.commandBuffer.pop();

I do not understand this bug because there is a this.commandBuffer.size() test !!!!!

please, explain me !!!

**EDIT FEB 25**

Im gonna try to replace LinkedList by ConcurrentLinkedDeque

**EDIT FEB 26**

Same error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque.screenNullResult(ConcurrentLinkedDeque.java:810)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque.removeFirst(ConcurrentLinkedDeque.java:990)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque.pop(ConcurrentLinkedDeque.java:1036)
    at GrblCommunicator.streamCommands(GrblCommunicator.java:167)
    at GrblCommunicator.responseMessage(GrblCommunicator.java:240)
    at ResponseMessageHandler.handleResponse(ResponseMessageHandler.java:33)
    at SerialConnectionJserial.serialEvent(SerialConnectionJserial.java:114)
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort$SerialPortEventListener.waitForSerialEvent(SerialPort.java:1391)
    at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort$SerialPortEventListener$1.run(SerialPort.java:1295)
```

Comment: how can `mylinkedlist` has a value to `peek` when its size is 0?

Comment: Because there is nothing in the list.

Comment: is this an implementation of or a pure LinkedList?

Comment: the question is not very clear: are you wondering why that happened (debugging question), or are you interested in some way to do that happen (more theoretical question)?

Comment: its a debugging question

Comment: Please edit your question and show us a [mre] which demonstrates an empty LinkedList whose `peek` method returns a non-null value.

Comment: Do you have a special implementation of `LinkedList` or can you ensure, that at the point, where the object is created, it is really a `java.util.LinkedList` that's being instantiated? I know that there are for example `Map` implementations that only return an estimate value, when calling `size()`.

Comment: Can you please display `System.out.println("Class: " + mylinkedlist.getClass().getName());`?

Comment: Let me explain : this code is for a CNC and stream command (linkedlist) to the CNC. Its a non-reproductible bug: It happen some time. I think it come from serial/usb communication noise. Whatever. To correct this bug by software adjustment i found this awesome thing: when bug = : peek() return a string value (command) but size is 0 (command list) .  So it throw a nullpointer. I can correct it, but i want understand why. Just why and how a peek() can return a value and in the same time the list size() returning 0 . Its non-sens.  I will add the getclass.getname to my next try .

Comment: mylinkedlist.getClass().getName() => java.util.LinkedList

Comment: @Ledahu Please add the "this code is for a CNC and ..." explanation to the question, it provides context. Are you running the code in some special JVM / computer for that CNC machinery, or is it running on a regular JVM (like the Oracle one)?

Comment: the bug appear again today ... its crasy . I edited with more code . please help . Its run JVM 1.8.0_231 , oracle

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for you to peek an item in a LinkedList AND have the size of it be zero. Think about what you're saying - "How can I look at this value and have the list have no values?". The reason for this is that `peek()` retrieves the first item in the list but does NOT remove it. *However*, you may be looking for `pop()` instead. Using `pop()` you can retrieve AND remove the first item at the same time. Per the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop()) "Pops an element from the stack represented by this list. In other words, removes and returns the first element of this list".

```java
LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();
myList.add("blablabla");
System.out.println("String: " + myList.pop() + ", Size: " + myList.size());
```

This prints out:

```
String: blablabla, Size: 0
```

Comment: yep. But its a debugging question . peek() return a value and size() is 0...

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely need to return a value when the size is 0, you have a few options.

1. Create your own `LinkedList` implementation
2. Catch the exception that will be thrown currently, and then return the value that you find appropriate for this scenario
3. Check the size of the linked list before calling `.peek()` and return the appropriate value *instead of calling* `.peek()` if the size is 0. If it is not 0, go ahead and make the call.

Answer (score -1):

Implementation of peak() method for java.util.LinkedList says that "Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list."

So with java.util.LinkedList it's not possible.

You may have imported LinkedList from some other library other that "java.util.LinkedList"

Comment: If after reading the answers we are editing our questions, We shouldn't down vote at least those answers.

Answer (score -1):

For now, the only explantation is in this thread

"A LinkedList is not thread-safe"

[Thread safety issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976466/thread-safety-issue)

so i will use : LinkedBlockingQueue